# Transpose Multiple Columns to Row, find what data are changes, maintain old value if no changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

OriData

```
+------------+-------------------+-------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|  Ori_Date  | Resubmission_Date | SeqNo |  IDNO  | PX_Name_OLD | Name_NEW | NameReason | PX_Gender_OLD | Gender_New | GenderReason |
+------------+-------------------+-------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-03        | A123  | ID123  | OldName     | NewName  | Valid      | L             | P          | Valid        |
| 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-03        | AB456 | A26589 | Captain     | IronMan  | Valid      | L             |            |              |
+------------+-------------------+-------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

Result I Want

```
+------------+-------------------+-------+--------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+--------+--------------+
|  Ori_Date  | Resubmission_Date | SeqNo |  IDNo  | Col_Chg | From_Value | To_Value |  Name   | NameReason | Gender | GenderReason |
+------------+-------------------+-------+--------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+--------+--------------+
| 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-03        | A123  | ID123  | Name    | OldName    | NewName  | NewName | Valid      | P      | NULL         |
| 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-03        | A123  | ID123  | Gender  | L          | P        | NewName | NULL       | P      | Valid        |
| 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-03        | AB456 | A26589 | Name    | Captain    | IronMan  | IronMan | Valid      | L      | NULL         |
+------------+-------------------+-------+--------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+--------+--------------+
```

Query that I wrote:

```
select Seqno, IDNo, ColName, Vals
from 
    (
        select  
                isnull(cast(reqid as nvarchar(255)), '') AS Seqno,
                isnull(cast(Name collate database_default as nvarchar(255)), '') as Name,
                isnull(cast(IDNo collate database_default as nvarchar(255)), '') as IDNo,
                isnull(cast(Gender collate database_default as nvarchar(255)), '') as Gender
        from #A
        where NameReason IS NOT NULL or GenderReason IS NOT NULL
    ) unpivot_table
    unpivot
        (
            vals for colname in (Name, Gender
        )
    ) unpivot_handle
```

Whenever there is a value in NameReason/GenderReason, then it **will triggered the changes** thats why in query i put NameReason or GenderReason IS NOT NULL.

PX = Table1-old value , xx_New = Table 2-new value (if any-but definitely there is an update for some of columns), I joined them together and insert to table #A.

Name column, if there is changes, will take New_Name column.

Gender column, if there no changes, will take PX_Gender aka old value.

With my query, I'm not able to get From_Value, To_Value, and other columns. Any idea how to get the result I want?

**Note: Im dealing with 10mil records, 20+ cols, I cannot hardcode it.**

Comment: I don't understand your desired results.  Why is gender both in columns and in an additional row?

Comment: @GordonLinoff if there is changes show the new result in all rows (under same idno). as you can see from idno:A26589, there is no changes for gender, so desired result is showing old value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select a.Ori_Date, a.Resubmission_Date, a.SeqNo, a.IDNO,
       v.*
from #a a cross apply
     (values ('Name', PX_Name_OLD, Name_NEW, NameReason),
             ('Gender', PX_Gender_OLD, Gender_New, GenderReason)
     ) v(Col_Chg, From_Value, To_Value, Reason)
where reason is not null;
```

Note:  This does not include all the columns that you have.  The additional gender columns seem redundant.

Comment: the result almost there but now i got new problem arise. its show all columns that even without changes. i tried playing around with 'where condition' but still no luck. because i only keep track that if 'reason' column is not null, meaning definitely the column got changes. even if FX_Occupation_old = value: A, in Occupation_new = value: B, but occupationReason is null, then no changes.

Comment: @user3542587 . . . That is based on the `where` clause.  Maybe it should be on the reason instead of the values.